# Getting the nearest instances from the past and the future

Tags: postgresql

I've got a table that contains `appointment` records, and the user selects a date range (`begin_date`, `end_date`). I would like to get the `appointment` that falls in this date range, as well as the closest instances in the past and future that fall outside of this date range (aka, the previous occurrence and the next occurrence).

I think the best way to approach this is using CTEs and self joins, but I'm open to another strategy. This is my current query:

```
WITH present AS
(SELECT appt.ewssubject, appt.ewsstart::DATE, appt.ewsend::DATE 
FROM appointment appt
WHERE (appt.ewsstart, appt.ewsend) OVERLAPS (begin_date::DATE, end_date::DATE))

SELECT 
present.ewssubject, present.ewsstart, present.ewsend, 
past.ewssubject AS pastsubject, past.ewsstart::DATE AS paststart,past.ewsend::DATE AS pastend,
future.ewssubject AS futuresubject, future.ewsstart::date AS futurestart, future.ewsend::date AS futureend

FROM present 
LEFT JOIN appointment AS past USING (ewssubject)
LEFT JOIN appointment AS future USING (ewssubject)

WHERE 
present.ewssubject = past.ewssubject AND
present.ewssubject = future.ewssubject AND
past.ewsend < present.ewsstart AND
future.ewsstart > present.ewsend

ORDER BY present.ewsstart ASC
```

I'm getting a huge list of `appointments`, and there are a lot of repeats -- like so:

```
subject  start       end         last_start  last_end    next_start  next_end
DINNER   2015-09-18  2015-09 18  2015-09-17  2015-09-17  2015-09-19  2015-09-19
DINNER   2015-09-18  2015-09 18  2015-09-17  2015-09-17  2015-09-19  2015-09-19
... // more repeats! :(
```

All I want to do is reduce the number of duplicates, like this format:

```
subject  start       end         last_start  last_end    next_start  next_end
DINNER   2015-09-18  2015-09-18  2015-09-17  2015-09-17  2015-09-19  2015-09-19
DINNER   2015-09-21  2015-09-21  2015-09-18  2015-09-18  2015-10-02  2015-10-02
... // and so on
```

n.b. An `appointment` can span multiple days.

How can I fix my query? Or is there another one I can write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not enter details about your data so I'm not sure whether this is a good idea, but you can probably use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html):

```
select
    ewssubject, ewsstart, ewsend,
    lag(ewsstart) over (partition by ewssubject order by ewstart) prior_start,
    lag(ewsend) over (partition by ewssubject order by ewstart) prior_end,
    lead(ewsstart) over (partition by ewssubject order by ewstart) next_start,
    lead(ewsend) over (partition by ewssubject order by ewstart) next_end
from appointment
order by ewstart;
```

Comment: this works! sorta...how can i make the `prior` and `next` dates unbounded by the user-selected `begin_date` and `end_date`? Currently this only works if the next and previous occurrences also happen in the specified date range